# validator.js with bootstrap how do you know your form is valid on AJAX forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using the [validtor js](https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) tutorial to add it to my project.

[image]

I run this when button is clicked:

```
$("#add_now_btn").click(function(event){
  //add now button 
  // event.preventDefault();   
  //$('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator();
  var result = $('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator('validate');
```

The result is object, so how do I know if my form is valid prior to my AJAX call? In my current case 'validator' just runs and submits the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docs](https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-options)

Try this

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function(e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
  }
})
```

And you can use `invalid.bs.validator` to find errors in form (this works  when a form field becomes invalid.)

```
$('form').validator().on('invalid.bs.validator', function (e) {    
    console.log(e)
})
```

And to get boolean value whether form is valid or not use this

```
$('form').validator().data('bs.validator').hasErrors();
```

returns true if  form has errors and false if form is valid.

Comment: hasErrors() was a relief :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not to try this way? :

```
$('#myOrderDetailsForm').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
  }
});
```

Comment: you can handle your ajax in `else` condition!?

Comment: no way , i could but i need to write each condition again , so why do i need a validator then , like